# How do you say "offset" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, sustantivos, informática

We use this word in IT to query some paged services. As they return a collection of objects, we can tell the service two different parameters to read all the pages. These are `limit` and `offset`.

How would you translate `offset` to Spanish?

Of course `limit` is translated as `límite`.

Google translate says it is `compensar` but we don't think that it's correct at all.

Used in a sentence:

> Hacé un pedido al servicio con un limite de 100 y un ***offset*** de 50.

Comment: A diferencia de otros grupos de Stack Exchange, en este se puede escribir las preguntas en español o en inglés, lo que más cómodo te resulte.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Una posible traducción puede ser **desplazamiento**.

Al fin y al cabo, realizas una búsqueda en un intervalo, con un límite y empezando desde otro punto; esto es, *desplazas* el origen.

Desde el momento que se desplaza el origen una cantidad determinada de elementos, desplazamiento cubre ese significado.

El [artículo de la Wikipedia en castellano sobre offset](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offset_(inform%C3%A1tica)) menciona esto también, indicando que

> En informática, un offset dentro de un array u otra estructura de
>   datos es un **entero que indica la distancia (desplazamiento) desde el
>   inicio del objeto hasta un punto o elemento dado**, presumiblemente
>   dentro del mismo objeto. El concepto de distancia es solamente válido
>   si todos los elementos del objeto son del mismo tamaño (típicamente
>   dados en bytes o palabras).

Comment: +1. La *única* otra palabra en que podría pensar sería *sangrado* pero por ser jerga técnica del mundo topográfico, pues, no sirve jaja.

Comment: Desplazamiento es la mejor opción, sin duda.

Answer (score 4):

Use in that numerical context as your example this could be translated to **"Margen de error"**
 Meaning you need to order 100 as limit with an offset of 50. As if your valid range is 50 (-50) to 150 (+50)

Comment: Qué acierto. _Margen de error_ sirve muy bien en la mayoría de los casos.

Comment: Me gusta la opción. Supongo que *margen* a secas también nos valdría, pues el *de error* aquí se sobreentiende.

Comment: Margen puede ser válida, margen de error... un offset no tiene por qué hacer referencia a un error, puede ser la cantidad de espacio que desplazas un elemento respecto a un punto dado.

Comment: Claro. La respuesta es "margen" en el contexto usado en el ejemplo pueda que se tome como margen de error. De hecho para aplicaciones como excel. Offset significa desplazamiento y margen no entra en contexto.

Comment: Lo importante es dar la idea y que todos aportemos algo.